# Check whether a value is present in parent or association and get the parent object in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have the following two models:

```
class Parent
  has_many :children

class Child
  belongs_to :parent
```

Now I need to check for the value of `city` attribute and get the `Parent`. Both the above models have the `city` columns. Sometime the values are different and sometimes they are same. I need to do a query like this:

```
city_name = #some city name
parents = Parent.where(city: city_name).presence || Parent.joins(:children).where(children: {city: city_name})
```

How can I combine this into a single sql or activerecord query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `or`:

```
Parent
  .joins(:children)
  .where(city: city_name)
  .or(Parent.joins(:children).where(children: { city: name }))
```

No matter if you use joins to get Parents by their city, when using joins you need to "prefix" the join table to filter their rows.

If you're not comfortable with that, you can use the string version

```
Parent
  .joins(:children)
  .where('parents.city = :city OR children.city = :city', city: city_name)
```

Comment: Can I use `joins` once and get the desired result?

Comment: No, because `or` will raise an error. Both statements must _be structurally compatible_. If you're not comfortable with that, you can use the string variation `Parent.joins(:children).where('parents.city = :city OR children.city = :city', city: city_name)`.

Comment: Your comment was the answer that I was looking for. Anyway I learnt about `or` method from your answer.